# create custom field and upload image in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image-upload

i'm trying to learn the way for uploading image file through custom field but cant get the easiest code to do it. i just done a bit here:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'create_image_box');
function create_image_box() {
add_meta_box( 'meta-box-id', 'Image Field', 'display_image_box', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}

//Display the image_box
function display_image_box() {
 global $post;
  $image_id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'xxxx_image', true);
 echo 'Upload an image: <input type="file" name="xxxx_image" id="xxxx_image" />';

// Upload done: show it now...(as thmbnail or 60 x 50)
```

anybody please take me to next step and show the way to display the image in blog page too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets go Stepwise here:

1. Create custom field Meta Box for inserting Image Url in post type => post.
2. Update/Save the custom field value in back end.
3. Display the custom field value in front end.

Seeing your code it seems that you are missing #2. Try the code below to save custom field:

```
function save_joe_details($post_id){
  global $post;
  if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
  return $post_id;
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "custom_field_image", $_POST["custom_field_image"] );
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_joe_details');
```

Code for #3 that displaying the custom field will be:

```
<?php global $post;
$custom_image = get_post_custom($post->ID); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $custom_image["custom_field_image"][0] ?>" />
```

Comment: thanks Joe for ur kind help..i just followed ur way & getting no error but somewhere im doing wrong thats y its not display the image..[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795277/display-image-from-custom-field-in-wordpress]

Comment: Try to confirm, whether the custom field holds any value in Post Editor or not. (If **Custom Fields Widget** is hidden then use Screen Options at the top of screen to make it visible.)

Comment: thanks 4ur reply..i just checked screen option and all marked as visible. do in made any wrong inside my code ? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795277/display-image-from-custom-field-in-wordpress]

Comment: Did you check the custom field value, if it is containing any image url or not?

Comment: its containing the file name only not url.. how can i get the url ?

Comment: Which means the file is not uploaded. You should refer to this article in order to insert image using wp-media uploader. [Add Upload Button in Meta box](http://www.thecreatology.com/add-multiple-image-upload-button-using-wordpress-uploader-in-theme.html)

Answer (score 0):

you could try wrap it in wp_get_attachment_url like this:-

```
wp_get_attachment_url( $custom_image["custom_field_image"][0] );
```