# wordpress custom post attachment fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating custom post fields all text fields are working fine but i am little bit confused in saving attachment field. its saving file name in database but not moving that file in upload directory .[image]

here is the code :

`   $sp_boxes = array (
    'Product Details' => array (

```
    array( 'author', 'Author / product:' ),  //text field
    array( 'filesize', 'File size / license:' ),//text field
     array( 'abc', 'Requirements: ' ),//text field
     array( 'screen', 'Screen Shots: ',"img" ),//Attachment Field

),`
```

* Attachemnet (upload image field is confusing )
   `add_action( 'admin_menu', 'sp_add_custom_box' );`
    // Use the save_post action to do something with the data entered
    // Save the custom fields
    `add_action( 'save_post', 'sp_save_postdata', 1, 2 );`
    // Adds a custom section to the "advanced" Post and Page edit screen`

`    function sp_add_custom_box() {
    global $sp_boxes;

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_meta_box' ) ) {

    foreach ( array_keys( $sp_boxes ) as $box_name ) {
        add_meta_box( $box_name, __( $box_name, 'sp' ), 'sp_post_custom_box', 'post',  'normal', 'high' );
    }
}
}

function sp_post_custom_box ( $obj, $box ) {
global $sp_boxes;
static $sp_nonce_flag = false;

// Run once
if ( ! $sp_nonce_flag ) {
    echo_sp_nonce();
    $sp_nonce_flag = true;
}

// Genrate box contents
foreach ( $sp_boxes[$box['id']] as $sp_box ) {
    echo field_html( $sp_box );
}
}

function field_html ( $args ) {

 switch ( $args[2] ) {

    case 'textarea':
        return text_area( $args );

    case 'checkbox':
        // To Do

    case 'radio':
        // To Do

    case 'text':
    case 'img':
    return attachment( $args );
    default:
        return text_field( $args );
}
}

function attachment ( $args ) {
global $post;

// adjust data
$args[2] = get_post_meta($post->ID, $args[0], true);
$args[1] = __($args[1], 'sp' );

$label_format =
      '<label for="%1$s">%2$s</label><br />'
    . '<input type="file" id="%1$s" name="%1$s" value="" size="25"><br /><br />';

return vsprintf( $label_format, $args );
}
function text_field ( $args ) {
global $post;

// adjust data
$args[2] = get_post_meta($post->ID, $args[0], true);
$args[1] = __($args[1], 'sp' );

$label_format =
      '<label for="%1$s">%2$s</label><br />'
    . '<input style="width: 95%%;" type="text" name="%1$s" value="%3$s" /><br /><br    />';

return vsprintf( $label_format, $args );
```

}

`

- And this is how i am saving post data

`    function sp_save_postdata($post_id, $post) {
    global $sp_boxes;

```
// verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
// because save_post can be triggered at other times
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['sp_nonce_name'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) ) {
    return $post->ID;
}

// Is the user allowed to edit the post or page?
if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post->ID ))
        return $post->ID;

} else {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
        return $post->ID;
}

// OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
// We'll put it into an array to make it easier to loop though.

// The data is already in $sp_boxes, but we need to flatten it out.
foreach ( $sp_boxes as $sp_box ) {
    foreach ( $sp_box as $sp_fields ) {
        $my_data[$sp_fields[0]] =  $_POST[$sp_fields[0]];
    }
}

// Add values of $my_data as custom fields
// Let's cycle through the $my_data array!
foreach ($my_data as $key => $value) {
    if ( 'revision' == $post->post_type  ) {
        // don't store custom data twice
        return;
    }

    // if $value is an array, make it a CSV (unlikely)
    $value = implode(',', (array)$value);

    if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE) ) {


        // Custom field has a value.
        update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);


    } else {

        // Custom field does not have a value.
        add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
    }

    if (!$value) {
enter code here
        // delete blanks
        delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key);
    }
}
}`
```

*All are working fine upload image field save the image name in db but image is  not moving  to upload directory.*
Anyone can help me???
thanks

Comment: Format ur code properly.

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya now i think you can check it...

Comment: its urgent please help me

Comment: Why u are using attachment as meta field?

Comment: I want to provide field to user for upload images (screen shots of products)

Comment: Refer this. May be help u. :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776444/create-custom-field-and-upload-image-in-wordpress

Comment: yes i checked it already but problem with me is that upload file name is saving correctly in db ,but file is no moving in directory, should it move??

Comment: Check this http://austinpassy.com/2010/creating-custom-metaboxes-and-the-built-in-uploader/

Comment: no, its also not working in my case....

Comment: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/attaching-files-to-your-posts-using-wordpress-custom-meta-boxes-part-1/

Comment: I am doing browsing from last two days I also checked this but its not providing me the solution whih i need ...

Answer (score 1):

Use this word press upload function in your save function :

```
           // Upload the goal image to the uploads directory, resize the image, then upload the resized version
            $goal_image_file = wp_upload_bits( $_FILES['post_media']['name'], null, wp_remote_get( $_FILES['post_media']['tmp_name'] ) );

            // Set post meta about this image. Need the comment ID and need the path.
            if( false == $goal_image_file['error'] ) {

              // Since we've already added the key for this, we'll just update it with the file.
              update_post_meta( $post_id, 'umb_file', $goal_image_file['url'] );

            }
```

Comment: 'post_media' is the name of input tag? ( in my case it would be %1$s) ?